# Shapiro-Wilk test

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to determine if a given sample comes from a Normal distribution. For that purpose I want to perform a [Shapiro-Wilk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) test in the way stated on wikipedia. My concern comes with the vector $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, whose computation requires the knowledge of the expected values $(m_1,\dots,m_n)$ for the order statistics. I have no clue of what is this nor how I could compute it. I know what a statistic is and what expectation is, but I'm having a hard time trying to find any insight on this specific ones. Any help would be most aprreciate.

Comment: Do you want the mathematical computations needed to calculate the expected values and variance-covariance matrix for the order statistics, or do you want to simply *apply* the test to some real data?

Comment: I want to apply the test to some real data, but knowing the general procedure wouldn't be dismissed :)

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question: regardless of how the $a_i$ are calculated, there exist tables with their approximate values for certain parameters, something that was unknown to me.

Here's a link to some examples: http://www.real-statistics.com/tests-normality-and-symmetry/statistical-tests-normality-symmetry/shapiro-wilk-test/